# How to check dynamic actual value in Webdriver/Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Scenario: am working with the ticket booking site, here if i selected the seat from table,the value should be increased by value 1..here i can able to match the expected value but can't able to verify it.

```
WebElement count = driver.findElement(By.id("ticketcnt"));
String text = count.getText();
Assert.assertTrue(text.matches("value is [0-9]{1,3}"));
```

1. Step 1: Login into the portal
2. Step 2: Select the "From" and "To" place and "Travelling BUS" NOTE: Default selected Seat Count is : "0"
3. Step 3: check for availability then select the Seat
4. Step 4: Seat should be selected NOTE: Selected Seat Count is :"1"(wanna
   check this value is increased depends upon the seat selection)

here my assert result is true because itz matching the numerical value. but i wanna verify that the value is increased r not..

Comment: Regex is not the right tool to compare numerical values. Get the previous value, match the new one in a group, convert the back-reference handling any parsing failure and then you can compare both.

Comment: Thank for the reply sir....String before selection = 0  String after selection = +1 itz my Scenario, how can i deal with this

Comment: I am not able to understand the issue in this question. Can you please edit your question and explain the scenario(maybe in steps) ?

Comment: I have explained the scenario in steps...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure im understanding the question correctly. But if you are sure that `count.getText()` is always going to be a number, then you can use this.

```
int newCount= Integer.parseInt(count.getText());
Assert.assertTrue(oldCount < newCount);
```